# C# - Get time from soundplayer

Tags: c#, soundplayer

Is there any way to get the number of milliseconds that have passed since the soundplayer started playing?

So far I'm using `Environment`'s tick counter by getting the start time and then the current time every frame, but sometimes that's inaccurate and sometimes it's really off.

At the beginning of the code I used

```
startTime = Environment.TickCount;
```

and then every frame i used

```
long elapsed = Environment.TickCount - startTime;
```

Is there an easier way to do this like HTML5 audio's `player.currentTime`?

Am I missing something obvious? Can someone explain to me why my question is bad rather than just downvoting? I just want some feedback...

Comment: If you can't use @MichaelEdenfield answer. You should try experimenting with the Timer class instead of Environment.TickCount.
Here is documentation for the Timer class [C# Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Timers.Timer(v=vs.110).aspx).


Furthermore i would suggest you to start using MSDN for reference, it's a great help as soon you learn it.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using `MediaPlayer` class instead.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `SoundPlayer` class has no way to read it's current position. It's a very simple "fire-and-forget" WAV player that's not meant for anything too complicated.

If you need more control over your sound playback you should be using something like the Windows Media Player control, as described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564582(v=vs.85).aspx). In particular, there is an [`IWMPControls::currentPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564740(v=vs.85).aspx) property you can get from the media player to tell you where in the current media the player is.