# Windows Form: Play sound, but not from beginning

Tags: c#, audio, soundplayer

I want to play a track (.wav file) in my `Windows Forms Application`. But I do not want it to play from the beginning, but from a certain point somewhere in the track (let's say 10 seconds).
To play the track from beginning is no problem:

```
private void playSimpleSound()
{
    SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\sound.wav");
    simpleSound.Play();
}
```

But how can I skip the first 10 secons, and play only the rest of it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot create a second wav file from the first that you edit to start where you want it to?

Comment: Not with SoundPlayer, no, but there are many other libraries you could use to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SoundPlayer` class not to support to do this. It gives a very simple control on WAV files. 
Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477174/c-sharp-get-time-from-soundplayer) can help you.