# Play sound from WAV file at a time offset from start in C#

Tags: c#, wav, audio-player, soundplayer

I'm trying to coordinate playing sound with displaying some other data on a graph recorded at the same time. If the user drags the graph forward or backwards how can I skip forward or backward in the WAV file so the sound is still coordinated? I can't see a time offset in APIs like [SoundPlayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Media.SoundPlayer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly, then use `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer` , add reference to "Windows Media Player" from COM and then you set the position by using:

```
 WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new  WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
 player.URL = file; //file to be played
 player.controls.play();
 player.controls.currentPosition = x; //set the position you want here when user drag
```

or you can use naudio, free opensource API, download it from codeplex:

[Naudio Library](https://naudio.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can't skip backward or forward using SoundPlayer.

[Windows Form: Play sound, but not from beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876872/windows-form-play-sound-but-not-from-beginning)

[C# - Get time from soundplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477174/c-sharp-get-time-from-soundplayer)